# How to specify sample dependent kernels/filters in Conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to implement a convolutional autoencoder where some of the convolutional filters are input content dependent. For example, in a simple toy example, knowing the digit label for MNIST could further help with reconstruction in an autoencoder setup.

The more general idea is that there could be some relevant, auxiliary information (whether the information is the class label or some other information) that that is useful to incorporate. While there are various ways to use this label/auxiliary information, I will do so through creating a separate convolutional filter. Let's say the model has 15 typical convolutional filters, I would like to add an additional convolutional filter that corresponds to the MNIST digit and can be thought of as an embedding of the digit in the form of a 3x3 kernel. We would use the digit as an additional input to the network and then learn a distinct kernel/filter embedding for each digit.

However, I am having difficulty implementing a convolutional filter/kernel that is input dependent. I am not using `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` layer because that takes in the # of filters to be used, but not the actual filter parameters to make this input dependent.

```
# load and preprocess data
num_classes = 10    
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = np.float32(x_train)/255, np.float32(x_test)/255
x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1), np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=num_classes)

num_filters = 15
input_img = layers.Input(shape=(28,28,1))
conv_0 = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3,3), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img) 

# embed the target as a 3x3 kernel/filter -> this should map to a distinct embedding for 
# each target 
target = layers.Input(shape=(10,))  
target_encoded = layers.Dense(9, activation='relu')(target) 
target_encoded = layers.Reshape((3,3,1,1))(target_encoded) 

# Using tf.nn.conv2d so that I can specify kernel
# Kernel needs to be a 4D tensor of dimensions (filter_height, filter_width, input_channels, output_channels) 
# which in this case is (3,3,1,1)
# However it is currently (None,3,3,1,1) because the first dimension is batch size so this doesn't work
target_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input_img, target_encoded, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

I am currently using `tf.nn.conv2d` which takes a kernel as input in the format (filter_height, filter_width, input_channels, output_channels). However, this doesn't work as is because data is fed in batches. Therefore, each sample in the batch has a label and therefore a corresponding kernel so the kernels are of shape (None, 3, 3, 1, 1) which is not compatible with the expected format. This is illustrated in the code chunk above (which doesn't work). What are potential work arounds? Is there a simpler way to implement this concept of an input dependent conv2d filter?

Comment: How would you perform inference on your network? it sounds like you need the input to contain the true number for your network to work. The problem with your ideal construction is that, given the true label as an input and as an output, an optimized CNN would learn the identity function `f(x)=x`. That is, your network would learn to take into account only the input label, multiplying all the other pixels by 0 and the input label by 1. This way, your CNN wouldn't learn at all.

Comment: @ibarrond This would be in the context of an autoencoder or variational autoencoder rather than classification, where we're trying to predict the label.  So the network takes both the image and some auxiliary info (which could be the label) and outputs the reconstructed image (or generated image in the context of vaes). The goal is to see if knowing the label or some other information can help with reconstruction/generation.

Answer (score 0):

## Making A Conv2D with SWAPPABLE kernel!

You'll need to make your own Conv2D that takes as input the image to process AND the kernel to use.

```
# Define our new Convolution
class DynamicConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding='SAME'):
        super(DynamicConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.padding = padding
    def call(self, input, kernel):
        return tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filters=kernel, 
                            strides=(1,1), padding=self.padding)
```

And let's test it out

```
dc2d = DynamicConv2D(padding='VALID')
input_tensor = np.ones([1,4,4,3],dtype=np.float32)
kernel_tensor = np.ones([2,2,3,1],dtype=np.float32)
dc2d(input_tensor, kernel_tensor)
```

returns

```
array([[[[12.], [12.], [12.]],
        [[12.], [12.], [12.]],
        [[12.], [12.], [12.]]]])
```

It looks like it works great... but there is a HUGE problem

## HUGE ISSUE WITH KERAS - BATCH BY DEFAULT

Yeah, so here is the deal: tensorflow keras is really really really set on everything being set up so the first dimension is the batch.  But if you look up above we have to specify the **ONE KERNEL** for the whole batch.  We can't pass in a batch of kernel_tensor**S**, but just one.

## THERE IS A WORK AROUND!

Let's borrow something from RNN training schemes, specifically we are going to solve this by being careful about what we send per batch.  More specifically, for a batch we are going to make sure all input images use the same kernel_tensor.  You'll have to figure out how you do that efficiently with your data pipeline, but here is an example to get you going.

## Working Code

(We will rewrite out dynamic conv2d so that it takes a category and stores its
own kernel per category)

```
# Define our new Convolution
class DynamicConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, padding='SAME', input_dim=10, kernel_shape=[3,3,1,8]):
        super(DynamicConv2D, self).__init__()
        self.padding = padding
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.kernel_shape = kernel_shape
        self.kernel_size = kernel_shape[0]*kernel_shape[1]*kernel_shape[2]*kernel_shape[3] # = 3*3*1*8
        self.category_to_kernel = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.input_dim,self.kernel_size)

    def call(self, input, categories):
        just_first_category = tf.slice(categories,(0,0),(1,1))
        flat_kernel = self.category_to_kernel(just_first_category)
        kernel = tf.reshape(flat_kernel,self.kernel_shape)
        return tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filters=kernel, strides=(1,1), padding=self.padding)
```

This class by default does a 3x3 convolution, reading in 1 filter from the previous layer and outputting 8

```
# Example output
dc2d = DynamicConv2D(padding='VALID')
image_data = np.ones([4,10,10,1],dtype=np.float32)

# prove that you can send in a different category and get different results
print( dc2d(image_data, [[3]]*4).numpy()[0,0,0,:3] )
print( dc2d(image_data, [[4]]*4).numpy()[0,0,0,:3] )

--------

[ 0.014 -0.002  0.108]
[ 0.021  0.014 -0.034]
```

## Use it to make a tf.Keras model

```
# model input
image_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1), dtype=tf.float32)
category_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32)

# do covolution
dynamic_conv2d = DynamicConv2D(padding='VALID')(image_input, category_input)

# make the model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[image_input, category_input], outputs=dynamic_conv2d)
```

And we can use the model like so

```
# use the model
input_as_tensor = tf.constant(image_data,dtype=tf.float32)
category_as_tensor = tf.constant([[4]]*4,dtype=tf.int32)
result = model.predict(x=(input_as_tensor, category_as_tensor))

print('The output shape is',result.shape)
print('The first 3 values of the first output image are', result[0,0,0,:3])

---------

The output shape is (4, 8, 8, 8)
The first 3 values of the first output image are [-0.028 -0.009  0.015]
```